# Faster solutions to my coding, replacing loop with...?

Tags: r

I have two lists of data where I like to match one variable to another and one within a interval. I did this through a loop, but it takes very long time. I'm trying to learn R and familiar with the lapply family and wondering if I can use it here somehow? Or if there is any other solution.

My solution:

```
x <- data.frame( A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,5), B =     c(67,49,49,59,68,91,67,48,49,67,91))
y <- data.frame( A = c(2,6,3,4,5,6,2,5,4,7,5), B =    c(67,50,49,59,50,91,67,50,49,68,91))

ko <- data.frame(c())

for(i in 1:11){
  wi <- which(y[,1] == x[i,1] & y[,2] <= (x[i,2] +10) & y[,2] >=     (x[i,2] - 10))
  t <- y[wi,]
  ko <- rbind(ko, t)
}
```

Returns desired result in `ko`.

Comment: It is likely that the `rbind` call is the biggest hit here.  It would be faster to pre-allocate `ko` and fill it in by row.

Answer (score 1):

We can merge then use filter on result:

```
# merge
res <- merge(x, y, by = "A")
# then filter on interval
res <- res[ res$B.y <= res$B.x + 10 &
              res$B.y >= res$B.x - 10, c("A", "B.y")]
colnames(res)[2] <- "B"

# compare to ko result, sort then check
ko <- ko[ order(ko$A, ko$B), ]
res <- res[ order(res$A, res$B), ]
all(ko == res)
# [1] TRUE
```